# Can't use ping in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ping

I'm not sure this question is relevant in this forum, but I really need your helps. I'm using Ubuntu 9.04, and when I do a ping to any ip or host, what I got were always 100% packet loss. This is terrible, since I cannot do many things in my textbook. Please help me to fix this problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Is this about just not being able to ping or not having any network connectivity?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/21903/cant-use-ping-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Work out where you first get 100% packet loss of ICMP pings. Try one or two pings to 127.0.0.1, your local external IP interface, your router (if any) or default gateway, ISP hosts (e.g. DNS server, mail server). Try `ping -c 3 -w 12` (stop after 3 pings or 12 seconds) and let it finish by itself rather than ending prematurely as some ping, network stacks or networks can cause long delays on ping transmissions: patience can be helpful.

[In particular, for Ubuntu, if you see long delays on sending pings (typically a 5s timeout when pinging by hostname), look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/80900 on how the avahi daemon can introduce these delays.]

Possible causes of ping loss:

1. You may be running a firewall that is discarding pings or ICMP (outbound or inbound)
2. There may be a router between the client and the server blocking or throttling pings or ICMP traffic
3. The host you are pinging may be set not to respond to pings or ICMP traffic

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a [traceroute](http://www.zytek.com/traceroute.man.html) to help discover where it's dying.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your pings are being rejected somewhere.  You should check to make sure that ICMP traffic is enabled on your router.  Are you able to ping the local host IP?

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like a firewall, but have you tried pinging localhost or `127.0.0.1` or your local IP address? If this works, then it's likely a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Use command:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Or:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Now use ping command

```
ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
```

If both command don't wor, check the firewall and allow ICMP protocol to all IPv4 and IPv6.