# Can't use ping in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t use ping in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/21859/cant-use-ping-in-ubuntu)

I'm not sure this question is relevant in this forum, but I really need your helps. I'm using Ubuntu 9.04, and when I do a ping to any ip or host, what I got were always 100% packet loss. This is terrible, since I cannot do many things in my textbook. Please help me to fix this problem. Thank you very much

Comment: What happens if you ping yourself?

Comment: +1 to gbarry
Are you sure that you are connected to a network... and if so is it dhcp? did you get an ip address?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/21859/cant-use-ping-in-ubuntu

Comment: This needs to be deleted, the other question has many of the answers needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning off your iptables firewall? It might be...over eager.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you have a bad network card and/or a bad patch cable. Was it working before and has now suddenly stopped?